# What does this function do? (why do we xor?)

Tags: algorithms, finite-fields

I stumbled across some source code on GitHub, but the author did not provide any documentation so I'm trying to figure it out by myself.

```
def s(k,x,mul=gf832_mul):
    if k==0:
        return x
    tmp = s(k-1,x,mul)
    result = mul(tmp,tmp)
return result ^ tmp
```

It's my understanding that this code just multiplies the second parameter by itself (in galois field) and then xors the result. It does this recursively k times. What I don't understand is *why*.

For example, for k=2, and x=4 it would be the same as doing this:

```
((4*4)^4 * (4*4)^4) ^ (4*4)^4
```

In the first iteration, temp will be `4`, and in the second it will be `(4*4)^4`. If k were 3, temp would be the aforementioned result for k=2 xor with itself. All done in `GF(8)`.

I can understand wanting to find the multiplication of two numbers in a GF, but why would you xor the result?

Comment: If you want to understand what the function does, find its callers and see how they use its output.

Comment: Which language is this?

Comment: python3 if i'm not wrong @J.G.

Comment: Presumably you are computing the $k$-th iterate of $x^2+x$ or something like that?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think this question might do well on [so]

Comment: Presumably, the elements of $GF(8)$ are represented as $3$-bit numbers, and XOR is the addition in $GF(8)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements of $GF(8)$ are presumably represented as $3$-bit numbers standing for vectors over $GF(2)$.  Then XOR is the addition in the field.

When $k=0$ the function returns $x$;

When $k=1$ the function returns $x^2+x$;

When $k=2$ the function returns $(x^2+x)^2+x^2+x$;

and so on, where addition and multiplication are in $GF(8)$.

Comment: Oh yeah, that makes a lot of sense. Thank you! Is there a name for this kind of polynomial?

Comment: In a comment, @user10354138 called it the $k$-th iterate of $x^2+x$, which seems like a good name to me.